# Can hazard ratios be undefined?

Tags: regression

Can a hazard ratio be undefined because you are comparing a "lower value" to a "higher value?"

For example, suppose you are interested in some variable $x \in [0, 100]$. Say you are interested in comparing 5 values of $x$. If you choose the highest value of $x$ to be the reference level... Would all the hazard ratios of the other values be undefined?

**Edit.** Suppose you have the following groups: $A,B,C$ and $D$ with $D$ as the reference level. You are looking at the outcome death for each of these groups. If there are no outcome events in group $A$ for example, would the hazards ratio for group $A$ be $0$ or undefined?

Comment: Could you state precisely what you mean by "hazard ratio" in this context?  Your use of the term does not seem consistent with [a standard definition](http://www.cancer.gov/dictionary?cdrid=618612).

Comment: @whuber: It is the ratio of hazard functions where a hazard function is the rate at which an event happens (e.g. death) in a short time interval.

Comment: That description doesn't match what you state in your question, Markk.  How do you construe values of a "variable" as if they were hazard functions?

Comment: @whuber: I am forming groups based on the values of $x$. For example all people with $x = 1.5$ form a group, all people with $x= 2.4534$ form a group etc... and then I am looking at some outcome event like death and choosing people in group $x = 2.35$ (for example) as the reference level.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you're doing, markk, but do not yet have a clear idea.  It would help to edit your question to describe your experiment, what you're measuring, how you're grouping, and what your analytical objective is.

Answer (score 1):

To make any valid comparison using standard statistical tests, you'd need to define your two groups you are comparing as part of the experimental design. It does not make sense to define  two groups based on one variable, and then compare that variable between the two groups.

Comment: Motulsky: I am comparing hazards ratios for 5 groups (with 1 of the groups as the reference group) based on some value of a continuous variable.

Comment: markk: I still don't understand what your experimental design is, what statistical test you plan to use, or what question you are asking on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I *think* you are asking:

It depends on how you coded the variable. Trying an applied example:

We have some continuous variable, lets say BMI, and an outcome, say time until first myocardial infarction. You want to find out what the hazard ratio is between a BMI of 25 as the referent group, and say 30, 40, 50 and 55.

Your question is what happens if there's no events in group 40.

If you used indicator variables to code these, my understanding is the hazard would be 0, not undefined. There is a probability, and it can be calculated - it just happens to be zero.

If you used a continuous variable for BMI, it doesn't matter. Regression - including survival-analysis techniques involving regression, with smooth over areas of missing data. You can get an estimate for 40 as it interpolates between other areas where you *do* have events - say 39 and 41. This is a problem however if for some reason your group doesn't just have 0 events through random chance, but because there's something about them that means they *can't* have the outcome. For example, the magic heart attack fairy protects you if you have a BMI of exactly 40 (there are clearly more realistic examples of this problem). This is called non-positivity, and it is a threat to the validity of your inference.